# Need Help populating array with JSON data using SwiftyJSON

Tags: arrays, swift, swifty-json

I want to populate an array I have with JSON data. I'm using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire. I'm new to parsing JSON, so i apologize for any ignorance on my end. The URL below is the url i'm inserting in getAllTimeAverage(). Any help would be awesome!! thanks!

This is the JSON Data
https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/history/BTCILS?period=alltime&format=json

This is the array i want to populate

```
var allTimeAverages: [Any] = []
```

These are my functions. I call them in my cellForRowAt:, when i print the allTimeAverages.count, I get back zero.

```
 func getAllTimeAverage(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                print("Sucess! Got the Bitcoin Data")
                let bitcointJSON : JSON = [JSON(response.result.value!)]

                self.updateAverageAllTime(json: bitcointJSON)

            } else {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                self.price = "Connection Issues"
            }
    }
}
func updateAverageAllTime(json: JSON) {
    if let allTimeAverage = json["average"].dictionaryObject {
        self.allTimeAverages.append(allTimeAverage)
    }
}


func getBitcoinData(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                print("Sucess! Got the Bitcoin Data")
                let bitcointJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                self.updateBitcoinData(json: bitcointJSON)

            } else {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                self.price = "Connection Issues"
            }
    }



}
```

Comment: Why are you using json["average"].dictionaryObject. do you want to fetch all values of `average`

Comment: I want to fetch all the values. @nasir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how this is to be done (I have taken a few values from the JSON API you have shared):

```
    let jsonString = "[{\"high\": 23043.41,\"open\": 21494.60,\"low\": 21338.34,\"average\": 21668.01,\"time\": \"2018-06-29 00:00:00\",\"volume\": 102148.30132998565},{\"high\": 22488.75,\"open\": 22405.51,\"low\": 21380.97,\"average\": 22241.29,\"time\": \"2018-06-28 00:00:00\",\"volume\": 69383.44795111718},{\"high\": 22491.85,\"open\": 22169.36,\"low\": 21940.47,\"average\": 22224.29,\"time\": \"2018-06-27 00:00:00\",\"volume\": 69884.07809550199},{\"high\": 22707.46,\"open\": 22635.32,\"low\": 22004.29,\"average\": 22480.86,\"time\": \"2018-06-26 00:00:00\",\"volume\": 71611.8914173987}]";

    if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let json = JSON(data: jsonData)
        let jsonArray = json.arrayValue

        let averagesArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["average"].doubleValue}
        let highArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["high"].doubleValue}
        let lowArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["low"].doubleValue}
        let volumeArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["volume"].doubleValue}
        let openArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["open"].doubleValue}

    }
```

**Making your solution work according to the above**:
In the following line, remove [] as you are already getting an array from the API.

```
let bitcoinJSON : JSON = [JSON(response.result.value!)]
```

so the above line will become

```
let bitcoinJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
```

Now, you can get the array value like I have done:

```
let jsonArray = bitcoinJSON.arrayValue
```

and now you can utilize the rest of the code (repeated below):

```
    let averagesArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["average"].doubleValue}
    let highArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["high"].doubleValue}
    let lowArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["low"].doubleValue}
    let volumeArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["volume"].doubleValue}
    let openArray = jsonArray.map{ $0["open"].doubleValue}
```

Comment: getting this error : Value of tuple type '(String, JSON)' has no member 'subscript'

Comment: i feel like i'm putting the constant is the wrong place. I'm not getting anything

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer (and/or select the answer) if it worked for you